# MongoDB geoNear query on legacy data returns inaccurate distance

Tags: mongodb, geolocation

I am experimenting with mongoDB geoNear query. I have a Collection with one document inside:

```
{
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "583d169df18ef10012ae8345"
                },                
                "location": {
                    "loc": [
                        103.7652117,
                        1.3150887
                    ],
                    "name": "",
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "583d169df18ef10012ae8346"
                    }
                },

}
```

The location.loc field is 2d indexed. Then I used a geoNear query on mongoDB command

```
 {
      "geoNear": "users",
       "near": [103.761614, 1.3172431],
       "num": 10
     }
```

The result distance returned from mongoDB is 0.004193433515629152 radians which corresponds to more than 20 km. However, these 2 coordinates are just 0.5 km apart. Is there anything I have done wrong? I know it must be some very silly thing, but I just couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query related to `$geoWithin or $centerSphere or $geoNear` location structure like this only:-

```
"location" : {
        "lng" : 77.15319738236303,
        "lat" : 28.434568229025803
    },
```

And then run your query. It will give you accurate result.

Comment: Hi Ashutosh, you mean to say that the document structure is wrong? I believe mongoDB does support nested location objects?